# How to convert a HEX value to an int in PHP

Tags: php, hex

I have a HEX value like this:

```
0x77b1774c931ea947dec707c71653099f
```

And I would like to get the following result:

```
1.590995877159802e+38
```

In JS I did this:

```
eval("(0x77b1774c931ea947dec707c71653099f)");
```

How can I do that in PHP?

Comment: `echo "1.590995877159802e+38"`, voila! you may want to provide more details...

Comment: @MehdiBounya upd

Comment: All you want is to print `1.590995877159802e+38` right? well, code in my 1st comment will work just fine, please provide what does the code do and what are you trying to achieve...

Comment: @MehdiBounya No, i want to convert "0x77b1774c931ea947dec707c71653099f" to "1.590995877159802e+38" in php. I know how do it in js, but dont know how in php

Comment: So rephrase your question, you mean *How to convert HEX to an integer in PHP?*, right?

Comment: @MehdiBounya yes. But all functions thats i trying in php dont return  double.

Comment: would you settle for a float ? :-0

Comment: @rtfm php floatval  return 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `hexdec()` function, just pass the hex to it like this:

```
echo hexdec("0x77b1774c931ea947dec707c71653099f"); // Result: 1.5909958771598E+38
```

This function will also convert numbers that are too big for an `int` to `float`

[Documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php)